# Between-person level interaction

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, interaction, multilevel-analysis

I have a database called dat1. Each participant (id) had multiple measurements. One of the variables measures type of the stress called stress_type (acute=0, chronic =1) and another variable is the stressful level of the stressor (continuous variable 0-3).

I wanted to examine the effect of the stressor type, stressful level and interaction of type*level of stress on depression.
I disentangled stress_type and stress level variables to get the within and between person mean, and calculated the within and between interaction as well.

mean_stress_type_rec = between person mean of stress type

mean_stress_level = between person mean of stress level

cent_stress_type_rec = within person mean of stress type

cent_stress_level = within person mean of stress level

I ran the following model:

```
res_intvsnonint_levels_int_nopleas <- lme(dep ~  mean_stress_type_rec * mean_stress_level +
 cent_stress_type_rec * cent_stress_level, 
 random = ~ cent_stress_type_rec + cent_stress_level _rec + obs_cent1 | id, data=dat1,
 na.action=na.omit,
 control=lmeControl(maxIter=1000, msMaxIter=1000, niterEM=1000, sing.tol=1e-20))
```

I found a very marginal interaction at the between level:

```
                    Coef.   SE         95% CI      t-value    p
Fixed effects                   
Intercept           29.28   4.42    20.61 – 37.96   6.62    <0.001
Time               -0.07    0.03    -0.13 – -0.01   -2.43   0.015
Type - between      4.46    6.47    -8.36 – 17.27   0.69    0.492
Type - within       0.41    0.59    -0.74 – 1.56    0.7     0.484
Level - between     2.14    2.6     -3.01 – 7.29    0.82    0.413
Level - within      0.41    0.35    -0.27 – 1.10    1.18    0.237
Type*Level - between-8.21   4.13    -16.40 – -0.03  -1.99   0.048
Type*Level - within  0.6    0.79    -0.96 – 2.16    0.76    0.448
```

I don't know what then I should do to further examine the between-level interaction. I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

In principle*, you can use emmeans emtrends for this. You need to choose a couple of "testing points" for your other continuous predictor. This is easiest if you standardize your predictors and choose for instance points -1, 0, 1 for predictor 1. This way you will be comparing predictor 2 slopes at predictor 1's levels of mean-1 SD, mean, and mean +1 SD, which I find is often reasonable way to test continuous-continuous interaction. So, first standardize your predictors, then run the model again with standardized predictors, then:

```
library(emmeans)
emtrends(modelname, pairwise ~ levelBetween, var = "levelWithin", at=list(levelBetween=c(-1,0,1))
```

You don't have to standardize though if you can find reasonable testing points from the predictor's raw values.

*However, I wonder about your stress type variable - can it really be understood as continuous? I understand you need to somehow get the mean value from it but I wonder what the resulting variable actually represents because it was originally categorical (?). But in principle you can use the above with a cont x cont interaction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I run the model using the standardized predictors I might lose disentangling the within and between person, am I correct? The model showed only the interaction of the between-person level of both stress type and stress level was significant (mean_stress_type_rec * mean_stress_level), which is what I'd like to understand. The within-person interaction was not significant. For clarification, the between-person variable of stress type is the proportion of the chronic (vs acute) events over the study.

Comment: You don't have to standardize anything, you can choose suitable points from your predictor's distribution in its current form. You can use the emtrends code I provided without standardization. Just change the -1, 0, 1 into values from the range of your predictor in its current form.

Comment: (however it seems that both variables in your significant interaction are between-subjects (level 2) variables i.e., have 1 value per participant - in which case standardizing them should not do anything to your model/interpretation. It's only level 1 variables you need to keep subject-mean centered in a multilevel model. But it may be I'm missing something here)

Comment: Yes, the significant interaction is in the between-subjects level. I disentangled the within and between variance. The interaction was n.s. in the within level. That's why I'm lost  regarding what I need to do in this case in which the interaction is in the between subjects level.